# How to escape line break already present in a string?

Tags: python, string, printing, escaping, line-breaks

I have a question, why does this:

```
testStr="\n"
testStr = "\\"+testStr
print testStr
>>> \
```

happen?
Shouldn't it now print `\n`?
I know about the `repr()` function, but I would rather solve this in another way
It would be very kind if you could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you type `testStr = "\n"` the special characters are already being interpreted. So in the next line you cannot change their interpretation as it already has happened. This is being done during [lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html) stage, so even way before the code is actually executed. When the string is being assigned to your variable the two characters "\" and "n" are already gone - there is only one character - the new line character.