# Write escape characters to file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file-io, escaping

I need to write in a file some text that contains some string with escape characters.

My problem is that implicit special character like a new line or a tabulation effect have to hold their behavior when the text is printed.

But the text that contains special character is to be printed as simple text.

I can't add a ***\\*** because this text is coming at runtime time and I don't know where these characters are.

An example:

```
header = """

newLineSymbol = '\n'


newValueSeparator = '\t'
"""
```

In my file I need to find:

```
newLineSymbol = '\n'


newValueSeparator = '\t'
```

I tried to open the file as *binary* to write with no success.

Last attempt to write the text using *repr* function, but it prints my text as:

```
\n\nnewLineSymbol = '\n'\n\n\nnewValueSeparator = '\t'\n
```

I use this to write:

```
fopen = open('output', 'w')
fopen.write(header)
fopen.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you use json ?

Comment: Because this is a static text filled with some part by a tool, i can only use it and its steps. I can only take its generated text and write it on a file.

Comment: Ok, and exactly why can't you replace `'\n'` with `'\\n'` ? What is the meaning of 'runtime time' ?

Comment: That text is composed by the tool, i keep it and i need to write in a file. So in some place of that text there are a sort of method used by the tool to fill the text. I can write the text only after that the tool generates it, so i can't know where and if it place some special characters as string.

Comment: What code are you using to print it to a file currently ? Can you please update your post with it ?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi just done

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is **impossible**.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363443/1925388) for the reason.
Quoting the answer:

> After you type testStr = "\n" the special characters are already being
>   interpreted. So in the next line you cannot change their
>   interpretation as it already has happened. This is being done during
>   lexical analysis stage, so even way before the code is actually
>   executed. When the string is being assigned to your variable the two
>   characters "\" and "n" are already gone - there is only one character
>   - the new line character.

In short, once the string has been declared, there is no difference between `'\n'` and an actual `<enter>` in the multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

you could try some string formatting like this:

```
    header = """

    newLineSymbol = '%s%s'


    newValueSeparator = '%s%s'
    """ % ('\\', 'n', '\\','t')

    fopen = open('output.txt', 'w')
    fopen.write(header)
    fopen.close()
```

Using the placeholders seems to work in this example, but I'm not sure how well it will work with other examples.  Hopefully, this will help with some other ideas though.

Comment: I solved using 'r' to define the long text. Instead to write *header = """.....\n\t"""*, i used *header = r""".....\n\t"""*